# Trying to move/animate a container in javascript using the easeljs library

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I am trying to adapt the [gamefromscratch](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/12/17/Gamedev-Math-Handling-sprite-based-shooting.aspx%22) page showing how to Handling sprite based shooting. But I'm trying to replace the sprite with a bitmap that's in a container. The point where I'm stumbling is the end of the onTick(delta) where there is a graphics object created , I don't know the syntax to replace

```
   var g = new createjs.Graphics();
                g.setStrokeStyle(5);
                g.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,0,0));
                g.drawCircle(this.x,this.y,10);

                this.bulletGraphic = new createjs.Shape(g);
                stage.addChild(this.bulletGraphic);
            }
            bullets.push(bullet);
```

with code that would work for a Bitmap In a container.
Thanks for looking .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for g.beginBitmapStroke() to replace the g.drawCircle()

You can find the EaselJS Documentation here:

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#yui_3_8_0pr2_2_1363403850534_598

Comment: could you put that in more context ? The container I'm trying to manipulate is called icon and I just replacing the g.drawCircle() with the g.beginBitmapStroke() I just get a type error

Answer (score 0):

For just using a Bitmap instead of a Shape you could use:

```
      this.bulletGraphic = new createjs.Bitmap('urlOrImage');
      stage.addChild(this.bulletGraphic);
    }
    bullets.push(bullet);
```

if you want the bullet-Bitmap additionally to be in a container (for whatever reason):

```
      this.bulletGraphic = new createjs.Container();
      this.bulletBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap('urlOrImage');
      this.bulletGraphic.addChild(this.bulletBitmap);
      stage.addChild(this.bulletGraphic);
    }
    bullets.push(bullet);
```

---

**A little sidenote from me (note related to your question, but in case you care):**
The code-example given on that page explains the Math behind the topic pretty good, but code-wise I would not take this as a good example. For a bullet you would usually create a new class, inheriting from `Shape` or `Bitmap`, the author of this example uses a plain object and just references the graphical-asset (this.bulletGraphic) through it. So if you're just using this to learn the Math, this is good, if you want to take this to create a real game out of it, I'd suggest you to restructure the code quite a bit, because this will get messy very soon.